# How to get no. of lines count that matches a string from all the files in a folder

Tags: linux, bash, shell

**Problem Description:-**  I have a folder which contains so many text files. I want to search for a particular string say "string_example" in all files in that folder.Then I should get the count of total no. of lines in all files which has the string "string_example". That means if there are 5 matching lines in 1st text file,10 matching lines in second text file, 3 matching lines in 3rd text file.Then the output should be 5+10+3=18

**What I Have tried:-**  I have surfed through the internet and found some commands like

- `grep -r -n ".string_example" .`

This bash command will print the file name along with line number of the lines which contains the string "string_example".Here is the sample output for better understanding

1st file:1:string_example is there

1st file:2:string_example is not there

2nd file:1:string_example is there

etc.......But the actaul output I want is 3 from the above output.

I have also tried few more bash commands but of no use.

**My Question**:- Is there any bash command for this kind of purpose.If not how to write a script for the following requirement.

Pls help me

Comment: reading your title I cannot understand if you need 'the total no of lines in all files that (that reference the files) contain(s) a string' or the total no of lines in all files that (that reference the lines) contain(s) a string'.  From the text of your Q, 'if there are 5 lines in 1st text file' it seems more  like the total no of lines in the file, but you may have made an ellipsis, meaning 'if there are 5 MATCHING lines in 1st text file', so I'm confused: you need total of total lines or total of matching lines?

Comment: Thanks for the comment I will edit accordingly!!

Comment: If I'm wrong, I'd suggest changing also the title, using something in the vein "... total number of **matching** lines in ...".  While we are at it, I'm not mother tongue but 'all files that contain**s**', isn't it strange?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can pipe your `grep` with `wc -l` to get count of lines containing your keyword:

```
grep -r "string_example" . | wc -l
```

Comment: Can u pls explain what does wc -l do??

Comment: @SUDHIR: `wc -l` counts number of lines in the given input.

Comment: If you get a lot of output from `grep -r` it might be more economical to do `grep -hrc "string-example" . | awk '{sum += $1} END { print sum }'` since then the output of `grep` will only be a per-file aggregate, not every hit.  On the other hand, it will include a zero for every file which doesn't contain a hit.

Comment: You need `--only-matching` to cover possible multiple occurrences in a single line, `grep -r --only-matching "string_example" . | wc -l`

Comment: But grep will just display single matching given pattern even if multiple matches are found.

Answer (score 4):

You could also use awk to do this:

```
awk '/string_example/{++c}END{print c}' *
```

`c` is incremented every time a line matches the pattern. Once all files have been read, print the total count.

Answer (score 2):

You want something like this?

```
grep -l string_example *|xargs wc -l
```

Edit:
You want to get numer of lines that matched in all files, or total numer of lines in files that contains matched  line?

Comment: I want to get numer of lines that matched in all files

Answer (score 0):

With this command given at the shell prompt you'll

```
% find -type f -name \*.h | xargs grep -l stdlib  | xargs wc -l | awk '{a+=$1} END{print a}'
16372
%
```

1. get a list of all files, here and under, ending in `.h`
2. grep these files to find references to `stdlib` and by the option `-l` print only (and once) the names of the files that have at least one match
3. pass the list of names to `wc -l`
4. use `awk` to sum the count of lines for each file